# Find the first matching string value in a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `strings` for example: `myList`
and then I also have a list of objects, for example `myDbObjectsList`
The object looks like this:

```
public class MyDbObjects
{  
    public string FirstName { get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

I want to know if there are any two members of `myList` (the first one above) that the value of one of them is equal to **FirstName** and the value of the other one is equal to **LastName** **on the same object** from my `myDbObjectsList` ?

I solved it with the obvious way of `for-each` ing through them and checking to see is it equal to this one, is it equal to that one etc, but I think there should be a more efficient way that people smarter than me can think of ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to search for objects who have the same FirstName and LastName. Can you post your code using foreach?

Comment: you should post your solution and what kind of efficiency you're looking for? time optimization? code optimization?

Comment: @Sandeep , my question is hard! but it is clear... please read it again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To speed up search you can put all strings from `myList` into hash set:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(myList);
```

Now to check if there any object from `myDbObjects` you can use `Any`:

```
var isAny = myDbObjects.Any(x => hashSet.Contains(x.FirstName) && hashSet.Contains(x.LastName));
```

And if you want to get those objects use `Where`

```
var objectsThatMatch = myDbObjects
  .Where(x => hashSet.Contains(x.FirstName) && hashSet.Contains(x.LastName));
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question, but can you explain why putting all the strings into a hash set speeds up the process?

Comment: @MindSwipe because search in `HashSet` will require `O(1)` complexity and search in a plain list wiil require `O(N)` where N is a list size. So in result we will have `O(M * 1)` complexity where M is a size of `myDbObjects` instead of `O(M*N)`

Comment: Hmm, one more thing: Can we enhance that to also check to make sure ALL of the items in the myList are also part of myDbObject ?  So for example currently it returns True if we have a string in myList that does NOT exists at all in myDbObjects ... but is there a way to also check for that ?

Comment: oh maybe I can use the length of objectsThatMatch and compare it to be equal to lenght of the myList .. if equal : all in there

Comment: @Bohn I don't think you can rely on length comparison. For example what if `myDbObjects` first and last name are equla to "A" and `myList` contains only one item "A"? Anyway it looks like a new question